# Editing a question to remove the "do not close this" plea

Tags: discussion

Take, for example, [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/41760/which-version-of-net-should-i-learn-to-find-a-job). The last paragraph is an explanation of how the question isn't a duplicate and references meta for justification. This explanation is longer than the question itself. Is it reasonable to edit it out of the question?

I'm personally not a fan of reading instructions to not close a question, but I can see how sometimes it may be useful to explain the reasoning behind asking a question that at first glance may look like a great candidate for closing. I edited the question this time, since it looks like the "it's not a duplicate" plea was only relevant on SO, but what's the common approach to that sort of thing?

Comment: <strike>Duplicate link? I didn't see it in the original.</strike> Duplicate on SO, got it.

Comment: IMHO, you did right.  If you hadn't done that I would have flagged it for mod attention anyway.  Asking viewers to go downvote someone elses answer doesn't seem right to me.  Neither does the way upvoting seems to have been only an afterthought.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems like the reason that these messages get created is that the user who posted the question "knows" it's not a duplicate but is finding it hard to explain *why* to everyone else.

In my opinion, the question *itself* should be edited so that it is apparent to other users that the question is not a duplicate.  If it really is a unique question, the body should be able to be worded in a way that makes that pretty obvious.

If that can't be done, it is a duplicate, and we should just vote to close, perhaps adding a comment.  Whether the plea is removed or not is kind of irrelevant at that point, but I'd favor removing it.

Answer (score 7):

If a question is obviously asking something different in the original then it should be easily inferred from the question, not by any pleas to not close.

If the questions are close, I think it would be fine to have one or two lines detailing why it is different.

Answer (score -1):

Great question. ( Not localizing on the OP's example)

In a community with so many people reading the question its likely That people may misinterpret or not go to the trouble of understanding the intentions behind the OP's seemingly duplicate question.
Due to

1. OP' lack of proper expression/wording
2. Which in turn maybe due to the OP's grasp of the language,due to missing factors in the questions definition which may be uncovered with a discussion and such.
3. Remember Not everyone is a Native speaker of English,not everyone one is an excellent or an effective communicator.
4. The point is to give the OP some benefit of doubt and concern to his requirement.I am not implying we go overboard on this,But we are an open community aren't we?
5. If the volume of people who might not understand this at the time of posting the question it would be closed very soon much to the frustration of the OP.
6. It may also be due to the Inability of the readers to see beyond the seeming duplicate nature to understand the real meaning of the question.Some people just don't take the trouble of understanding the question properly.
7. Agreed that some users might find it tiring/worn out /annoying to what they think is a duplicate post.IT wouldn't kill them to just ignore or not post in the topic for a while at least until it gets some constructive answers.Luckily we see this happening often :) thats why seemingly duplicate posts get some answers before they are closed .

> In my opinion, the question itself
>   should be edited so that it is
>   apparent to other users that the
>   question is not a duplicate. If it
>   really is a unique question, the body
>   should be able to be worded in a way
>   that makes that pretty obvious.
>   -[Renesis](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2314/renesis)

**The Plea should stay as is. If its too long it should be shorted.If it is removed *It Defeats The Basic Purpose of Putting it There*** to prevent the people who jump to quick conclusions and who dont take the trouble of understanding the OP's requirement in the question. *The fact that the OP has indicated that his question may be a duplicate indicates that he has been through the other posts and understands ,needs something more or better*.Which is totally ignored by the people who just want to close the topic.

Comment: That doesn't address that the plea shouldn't be part of the question itself, but rather belongs in a comment

Comment: I agree with you, having been a victim of non-dupicate questions getting closed,  The users chasing badges just take a cursory look and vote.